# Create a new column and generate numbers in that column using TSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table as below:

```
employee_name employee_address
RON           23-B, TORONTO
PETER         15-C, NY
TED           23-C, LONDON
RON           23-B, TORONTO
```

I have to add a new column to this table as follows:

```
employee_name employee_address   employee_no
RON           23-B, TORONTO      1
PETER         15-C, NY           2
TED           23-C, LONDON       3
RON           23-B, TORONTO      1
```

Basically I have to assign unique numbers if the employee_name and employee_address column is different. If these two columns are same then assign same number as shown in above table. I have to do this using TSQL. Can anyone please help?

Thanks.

Comment: I am using sql server 2008 R2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer the question asked

```
/*To add the new column*/
ALTER TABLE emps ADD employee_no INT NULL

/*To populate it*/
;WITH T
     AS (SELECT employee_no,
                dense_rank() OVER (ORDER BY employee_name, employee_address) AS
                new_employee_no
         FROM   emps)
UPDATE T
SET    employee_no = new_employee_no
```

But what is the use case for this? If you only have those 3 columns just delete the dupes and add an `identity` column.

Even if you do have additional columns not shown in the question that would mean that the rows are not exact duplicates you would still be left with a denormalised table that should very probably be re factored  into two.

Comment: I am getting invalid column name. employee_no

Comment: You can't have added that column to your table yet then. But see my question about why are you doing this.

Comment: no I need duplicates and the above query removes the duplicates.

Comment: @us111 - The above query doesn't remove anything it contains no `DELETE` statement...